# Append text to animated bar chart in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add some text at the end of the bars of a d3js bar chart.

The bar chart has transition with a delay. The source code can be found here https://bl.ocks.org/deciob/ffd5c65629e43449246cb80a0af280c7.

Unfortunately, with my code below the text does not follow the bars and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I thought the append text should be placed in the drawBars function no?

```
function drawBars(el, data, t) {
      let barsG = el.select('.bars-g')
      if (barsG.empty()) {
        barsG = el.append('g')
          .attr('class', 'bars-g');
          }

      const bars = barsG
        .selectAll('.bar')
        .data(data, yAccessor);

bars.exit()
        .remove();
bars.enter()
        .append('rect')
          .attr('class', d => d.geoCode === 'WLD' ? 'bar wld' : 'bar')
          .attr('x', leftPadding)
          .attr('fill', function (d) {return d.geoColor;})

bars.enter()
        .append('text')
          .attr('x', d => xScale(xAccessor(d)))
          .attr('y', d => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
          .text('Hello')

        .merge(bars).transition(t)
          .attr('y', d => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
          .attr('width', d => xScale(xAccessor(d)))
          .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth())
          .delay(delay)
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the text to follow the bars (and also later for the text to be updated to another value).

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, for anyone wondering you need to create a new function (eg: drawText()) and call it in later just below where the drawBars() function is called:

```
function drawText(el, data, t) {
          var labels = svg.selectAll('.label')
              .data(data, yAccessor);

          var new_labels = labels
              .enter()
              .append('text')
              .attr('class', 'label')
              .attr('opacity', 0)
              .attr('y', d => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
              .attr('fill', 'blue')
              .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')

          new_labels.merge(labels)
              .transition(t)
              .attr('opacity', 1)
              .attr('x', d => xScale(xAccessor(d))+50)
              .attr('y', d => yScale(yAccessor(d)))
              .text(function(d) {
                  return d.value;
              });

          labels
              .exit()
              .transition(t)
              .attr('y', height)
              .attr('opacity', 0)
              .remove();
}
```